# Mysql TRIM/RTRIM/REPLACE doesn't work to remove trailing spaces from an email column

Tags: mysql, sql, whitespace, trim

I have this insert select statement, copying data from employee bulk add staging to employee table:

```
INSERT INTO employee (tr_email) 
SELECT TRIM(eb.tr_email)
  FROM employee_bulkadd_staging eb
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE     
  tr_email=(SELECT IF(eb.tr_email = '' or eb.tr_email IS NULL, employee.tr_email,TRIM(eb.tr_email)));
```

Even if I change it to RTRIM or REPLACE(eb.tr_email, ' ', '') to replace the spaces with nothing it will still not modify the data to be inserted. I cannot get my login to work since my backend application detects these trailing white spaces at the end of the email address.

Sample email value with spaces is like this, highlighted to show the spaces:

[image]

The email address column from the source table, the data type is `varchar(100) utf8_general_ci`

while the target table the email column is `varchar(100) latin1_swedish_ci`

I am using MySQL 5. Thanks of any help.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Start an SQL question by showing the schema for all the relevant tables. Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` for each table, and paste it into the questions as text (NOT A PICTURE). 
An example of the data contained in these tables is also very useful. 
If at all possible create a SQLFiddle with the schema defined and some test data provided.

Comment: TRIM will remove trailing spaces but a char datatype will add them back in to the length specified https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html - which is why you should show table definition so that we can eliminate this possibility.

Comment: also tr_email=(SELECT IF(eb.tr_email = '' or eb.tr_email IS NULL, employee.tr_email,TRIM(eb.tr_email))); - you should qualify tr_email consistently and change the select to a case statement.

Comment: hello everyone. I have updated my question. Please let me know if the information I have provided is enough. Thanks

Comment: From the picture you have added it looks like there are line/carriage returns in your string and the TRIM function will only remove spaces

Comment: Varchar datatypes do not retain trailing spaces so what you see in source are not spaces and it's anybody's guess what they are when you post an image rather than data.

Comment: @NickW, so there are different type of spaces. I thought I can get rid all of them at once. How should I remove them though, the line/carriages?

Comment: 'so there are different type of space' - not the correct interpretation some characters are non printing eg cr/lf but not spaces in ascii a space is dec(32) a line feed is dec(10) https://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @P.Salmon,sorry I'm not sure what data you meant that I should post or how should I post it. I'm sure though on the image I sent, from the source which is a CSV file, and the staging table in the database, the email adresseses looks like that when I highlight them. And if I remove that extra spaces, everything works fine.

Comment: 'And if I remove that extra spaces' - not so you are deleting characters even the non printing ones. Some csv data would be useful as text..since that seems to be your raw data. Also how are you importing to staging. NB AMENDED to secure privacy but capable of reproducing your issue

Comment: @P.Salmon 'Also how are you importing to staging' - via phpMyadmin import wizard. I select a CSV file to import the staging table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are facing this problem due to CHAR(10) in your text. Can you try removing it -

```
REPLACE(eb.tr_email, CHAR(10), '')
```

Comment: What is char(13)? I haven't set that anywhere. Let me try this though. I'll update here for the results.

Comment: https://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @Ankit I have tried this as well as replacing CHAR(11) but no luck.

Comment: hmmm. Char(10) seem to have worked.

Comment: Exactly. I was feeling the sense that this might be the only issue. Happy programming.

Answer (score 1):

I've coded your data and can't reproduce the problem of spaces.
Is it a problem with a carriage return or newline character: char(11) and/or char(13) as Ankit suggests? I've added markers `<` and  `>` to make it clearer where there are whitespace characters.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE employee (
>     id int not null auto_increment primary key,
>     tr_email varchar(100) 
>     collate latin1_swedish_ci
>     )
>     ;
> CREATE TABLE employee_bulkadd_staging(
>     id int not null auto_increment primary key,
>     tr_email varchar(100) 
>     collate utf8_general_ci
>     )
>     ;
> ```

> ```
> insert into employee_bulkadd_staging (tr_email)
> values ('name@domain.com   
> ');
> ```

> ```
> insert into employee (tr_email)
> select trim(REPLACE(tr_email,'
> ','')) from employee_bulkadd_staging
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO employee (tr_email) 
> SELECT TRIM(eb.tr_email)
>   FROM employee_bulkadd_staging eb
>   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE     
>   tr_email=(SELECT IF(eb.tr_email = '' or eb.tr_email IS NULL, employee.tr_email,TRIM(eb.tr_email)))
> ```

> ```
> select 
> concat('<',tr_email,'>' )
> ,
> REPLACE(concat('<',tr_email,'>' ), '
> ', '')r
> from employee_bulkadd_staging eb
> ```
>
> ```
> concat('<',tr_email,'>' ) | r                   
> :------------------------ | :-------------------
> <name@domain.com   <br>>  | <name@domain.com   >
> ```

> ```
> select id,concat('<',tr_email,'>') ebs from
>  employee_bulkadd_staging;
>  
> select id, concat('<',tr_email,'>' ) emp 
>  from employee;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | ebs                     
> -: | :-----------------------
>  1 | <name@domain.com   <br>>
>
> id | emp                     
> -: | :-----------------------
>  1 | <name@domain.com>       
>  2 | <name@domain.com   <br>>
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6970c5ac1e7fc8b4744a16169afc173d)*

Comment: Thanks for your input. CHAR(10) was causing the issue, replaced it with nothing and it has now trimmed the spaces.